# Play! Framework and ElasticSearch StackOverflowError

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, elasticsearch

I'm using Play! Framework version 2.1.5, with Jest 0.0.4 and ElasticSearch 0.90.5 on QBox.io.

I have the following bit of code:

```
try {
    SearchConfig config = new SearchConfig(); 
    JestClient client = config.jestClient();
    Logger.debug("client exists");
    Index index = new Index.Builder(post).index("ads").type("ad").build();
    Logger.debug("index exists");

    client.execute(index);
    Logger.debug("post client.execute()");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which gives me the following error when I run it:

```
[debug] application - client exists
[debug] application - index exists
[debug] application - index: io.searchbox.core.Index@2ddf188f
[error] application - 

! @6fnicco9i - Internal server error, for (POST) [/user/posts] ->

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: java.lang.StackOverflowError]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:287) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.5]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:381) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.5]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$play$core$server$netty$PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$handle$1$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:143) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.5]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$play$core$server$netty$PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$handle$1$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:139) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.5]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.5]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.5]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at play.libs.F$Promise$6.apply(F.java:401) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.5]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.liftedTree2$1(Future.scala:253) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:249) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:249) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:29) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.liftedTree1$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:67) ~[akka-actor_2.10.jar:na]
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.writeDeferredName(JsonWriter.java:401) ~[gson-2.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.value(JsonWriter.java:495) ~[gson-2.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.write(TypeAdapters.java:246) ~[gson-2.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.write(TypeAdapters.java:231) ~[gson-2.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68) ~[gson-2.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89) ~[gson-2.2.3.jar:na]
[info] Compiling 1 Java source to /home/bcarlson/git/drillist/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[error] /home/bcarlson/git/drillist/app/controllers/Application.java:120: error: <identifier> expected
[error]                 Logger.debug("index: " + index.);
[error]                                                ^
[error] 1 error
[error] (compile:compile) javac returned nonzero exit code
```

I'm new to Play and ElasticSearch (and Jest), and I'm not figuring out how to troubleshoot this SOError. Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

-Ben

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the stack size of your app does not help?

Can be done with the jvm option -Xss4m where 4m is something larger than the default on your os.

Comment: I was unable to get it to work using Jest using marshalling and unmarshalling. I ended up just returning the object ID's and building an object array from them. I'll continue looking into this, but I couldn't figure it out.